# Making pandoc available to root user on linux

Tags: linux, pandoc, rstudio-server

I'm trying to render some `.rmd` files into `.pdf` beamer slides from a remote linux box. These will be `cron` jobs so will be run by `su`.

When I am logged into the box as my user, I can see that `pandoc` is installed and my `render()` statement runs

[image]

The pandoc version available to my user through `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` is `2.3.1.`

[image]

When I elevate to the root user with `sudo su` and and try to run the `render()` statements, I get an error:

[image]

I look for pandoc as root and get an error:

[image]

I run R as root and use `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` and get

[image]

I've tried the running the last two commands [on this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmarkdown/vignettes/pandoc.html) but that has not helped.

How can I make the pandoc available to my user also available to root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change to root, your PATH changes and it no longer includes `/usr/local/bin`.  You can see from the output of `which` that it is only searching `/sbin`, `/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, and `/usr/bin`.

So, you could add `/usr/local/bin` to your path: as root,

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

or you could just run pandoc with an explicit path:

```
/usr/local/bin/pandoc --version
```